# Preposition to vs. into

Tags: prepositions

As I'm not an ELL, I'm posting this question here.

It seems that both are grammatically correct:

"Please send those documents into my e-mail"
"Please send those documents to my e-mail"

What are the differences in semantics in these two usages? It seems "into my e-mail" signifies documents being in the e-mail mailbox, and "to my e-mail" is really an ellipsis of "to my e-mail address"?

Comment: I'd agree with your analysis but I would think for most people they could be considered equivalent (and have the same end result).

Comment: Yes, it's a different metaphor. _In_ implies a container, so one is speaking of _those documents_ as being physical (probly paper) and of _putting_ them as physical placement in a container. Perfectly cromulent, and so is the other one, which speaks of _those documents_ as being _files_ made of electrons, not paper, and can be transferred electronically (which is to say, sort of physically, but only for electrons). These two are both instantiations of the Conduit Metaphor, which says that meaning is contained in sentences and can be extracted by addressees.